# Pre-populate the sms body text with an https url

Tags: ios, html

I am trying to pre-populate an sms with text and an url. But the iOS is removing the whole url and only the text "https" is left in the text.

**Code:**

```
<a href="sms:&body=Look at this awesome link: https://nat5.com/workout">Send SMS</a>
```

**In SMS:**

```
Look at this awesome link: https
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are already in a link, you need to encode the URL (the `:` and slashes `/` to be specific).

As example, `https://example.com` would become `https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com`

In your case, you'd need to change your URL to `https%3A%2F%2Fnat5.com%2Fworkout`.
Full link:

```
<a href="sms:&body=Look at this awesome link: https%3A%2F%2Fnat5.com%2Fworkout">Send SMS</a>
```

Reference to URL encoding: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

And just as a side note: Both ways are looking to work on Android (At least on Android 7.0)

Comment: Glad I could help you!